# Permission to change post Author

Tags: author, permissions, user-roles

I am trying to create a "limited admin" but I cannot manage to give this user rights to change the author of posts.

The regular administrator can see the dropdown option to change author from both Quick Edit and Edit. The "custom" Admin **cannot** see the dropdown menu either in the quick edit or the normal edit.

I don't really know what else I could be missing, I activated almost every "role" for this user:

[image: First group of roles]
[image: Second group of roles]

Comment: Looks like you're using a plugin so your question should be directed to the plugins authors forum.

Comment: Thought those were "standard" permissions. I mean, if I weren't be using this plugin, how would I be able to add this permission to an Editor for example?

Comment: I don't want to open a new thread but after many different tries I am able to change the author of a post only with the administrator. Is this the normal behavior of WordPress?

Comment: Have you tried add_cap with a custom role? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Answer (score -2):

Checkout [User Roles and Capabilities Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/)

Comment: Link only answers are not highly praised here.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful. Also: The OP is already using a plugin for exactly that.